# Elementary proof that $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$ is not homeomorphic to a sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, invariant-theory

Ok, if one looks at invariants like the fundamental group, the Euler characteristic or orientability, then it is immediate to see that $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Is there any simple (or maybe not simple but still intersting) proof of this fact that makse no use of sophisticated invariants? (like homology, homotopy etc...)

The purpose is to teach this fact to a class without any of such tools.

Comment: A simple loop always cuts a sphere into two parts.

Comment: this is a big theorem

Comment: Will such a class appreciate what $\Bbb RP^2$ is?

Comment: @Arthur I hope so :)

Comment: Well, I think you have it backwards. The tools you mention are useful partly _because_ they very easily prove things like this. Trying to avoid them seems unpedagogical to me. Of course, if you have some really long proof not using them, and then show how simply it can be proven if you use them, then that's another story.

Comment: @user126154 The Jordan curve theorem is a "big theorem," but it is quite intuitive.

Comment: @Arthur  You are right, but maybe there is a nice proof that I don't know.

Comment: The Jordan Curve Theorem itself is, perhaps, a better example of the phenomenon you are pondering. The JCT  does have "simple" proofs that "make no use of sophisticated invariants", but they are very very messy, intricate proofs. So if the first proof of the JCT that you ever saw was one of those "simple" proofs, you would be very pleased when you finally saw it proved using algebraic topology. Take a look at the discussion over here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8521/nice-proof-of-the-jordan-curve-theorem

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to check that removing a point from the sphere gives you something that continuously retracts to a point, whereas removing a point from the real projective plane gives you something that retracts to a circle. Therefore they can't be homeomorphic.

If you don't want to work with retractions, note that removing a point from a sphere leaves you with a disk, whereas removing a point from the real projective plane leaves you with an open Mobius band.

Comment: why an open disc is different from an open moebius band?

Comment: This follows from the Jordan curve theorem that you mentioned in the *comments*.  Removing the central loop of the Mobius band produces an annulus, but removing a loop from a disk produces two connected components.

Comment: I don't see any way to make either of these approaches work without using any of the big tools OP specifically said they want to avoid.

Comment: Anyway JCT is considerably older than the invariants from algebraic topology mentioned in the OP's *question*, and also admits a nice hyperreal proof by Kanovei in *Real Analysis Exchange*. @EricWofsey